# Htaccess redirects from digits at the end

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make redirects from urls like

```
/test/112321  to /test/
/test/test2/1311223 /test/test2/
```

There are only digits in the end of the url.

Now i have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)([0-9]*)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.
Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` as you're matching `REQUEST_URI` which you can do in `RewriteRule` itself.

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$
```

rather than:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)([0-9]*)/$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1
```